# BootstrapVue navbar item positions problem

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, uinavigationbar

I installed bootstrapvue trough the CLI and used this navbar:
http://codeply.com/go/qhaBrcWp3v
[image]

But when I use in my Vue component I get this instead:
[image]

How can I get the stuff on the right to align right in Vue.js ?

I've tried with other navbar same happens.

I'm using :

```
  "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
  "vue": "^2.6.14", 
  "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
  "sass": "^1.39.0",
```

Comment: Do you have `ml-auto` on `Right Link` ?

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately